# в IE 11 не видно заголовка

Tags: html, css

Всем привет.

В чем может быть проблема, что в IE 11 не видно заголовка, в мобильной версии. В тот момент, когда в других браузерах все хорошо.

[image: скрин проблемы]

```css
.header--top {
  display: flex;
}

.header {
  /*(max-width: 900px)*/
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 200;
}

.page--header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eeefef;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="header--top">
    <a href="index.html" class="logo">
      <img src="images/base/logo.png" alt="logo">
      <img src="images/base/mobile-logo.png" alt="logo">
    </a>
    <div class="header--top-right">
      <div class="news">
        <a href="news-detail.html" class="news--item">
          <img src="images/data/news1.png" alt="news">
          <h2>Honda atv rea</h2>
          <p>Nu skall kvarvarande 2011 och 2012 arsmodeller av fyrhjulingar bort.</p>
        </a>
        <a href="news-detail.html" class="news--item">
          <img src="images/data/news2.png" alt="news">
          <h2>2013 Års ATV maskiner</h2>
          <p>Nu kommer 2013 års TRX fyrhjulingar.</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="facebook-like">
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/hondamccenter" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false"></div>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="menu-toggle"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="menu">
    <div class="default-menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">hem</a></li>
        <li><a href="offers-list.html">erbjudanden</a></li>
        <li><a href="">aterförsäljare</a></li>
        <li><a href="news-list.html">Nyheter</a></li>
        <li><a href="textpage.html">info & kontakt</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mobile-menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">hem</a></li>
        <li><a href="offers-list.html">erbjudanden</a></li>
        <li><a href="">aterförsäljare</a></li>
        <li><a href="news-list.html">Nyheter</a></li>
        <li><a href="textpage.html">info & kontakt</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<main class="main">
  <section class="page">
    <header class="page--header">
      <nav class="nav-header">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Hem</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <h1>nyheter</h1>
    </header>
```

Comment: Добавьте код, чтобы можно было разобраться в чем проблема.

Comment: Что за мобильная версия `IE-11` ? Зачем тебе это надо....???  Просто любопытство раздирает...

Comment: Делаю проект. Который должен быть адаптирован под мобильные телефоны тоже. Но в IE выглядит не так как надо.

Comment: Ты в каком тел видел `IE-11`, это не издевательство, я реально интересуюсь.... Я реально ни где не видел....  В тел `microsoft` `EDGE`

Comment: Ну... я тоже нет. Значит оставлю так. Полная версия то рабочая :D

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/dev-guides/dn736066(v=vs.85) - хотя ....

Comment: Я сколько раз на мобильных или планшетах винду ставил, я там `IE` не встречал...  Про кнопочные старые тел с `windows-phone` не скажу, не связывался. Хотя думаю их в расчет мы не берем)))

Comment: Значит я зря беспокоюсь?

Comment: Уверен на 99%...)))  Но я бы уточнил у заказчика....   Поищи в сети инфу об этом...    Моя уверенность, связанна лишь с 10 летним опытом по перепрошике  разного рода тел, планшетов и  дивайсов...  от яблока до андроида....

Comment: Ладно. Все равно спасибо:)

Comment: Судя по скриншоту у вас не мобильная версия `IE 11`, а десктопная `IE 11` уменьшенная по ширине до `380px`. Я, надеюсь, сотальные мобильные браузеры вы не так тестите?

Comment: Да вы правы. Другие мобильные браузеры я тестирую через inspect element и нажимаю на Responsive Design Mode.